# Renaming keys in multidimentional php array as per reference

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, key, rename

I'm trying to rename keys on my multidimensional array, based on second array holding the correct names.

My multidimensional array

```
$earth = Array (
  World => Array(
    Europe => Array(
      Portugal => Array()
      spain => Array()
      France => Array()
    )
    asia => Array(
      Japan => Array()
      China => Array()
    )
  )
```

and correct names array:

```
$rename = Array (
  [asia] => Asia
  [spain] => Spain
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

piece of cake

---

arrays: *earth* and *rename*

```
    $earth = Array(
    'World' => Array(
        'Europe' => Array(
            'Portugal' => Array(),
            'spain' => Array(),
            'France' => Array()
            ),
        'asia' => Array(
            'Japan' => Array(),
            'China' => Array()
            )
        )
    );

    $rename = Array (
      'asia' => 'Asia',
      'spain' => 'Spain'
    );
```

and call this function with em

```
function test_rename(&$earth,$rename){
    foreach ($earth as $e => &$y) {
        if(in_array($e, array_keys($rename))){
            $earth[$rename[$e]] = $earth[$e];
            unset($earth[$e]);
        }
        if(is_array($y)){
            test_rename($y,$rename);
        }
    }
}

test_rename($earth,$rename);
```

This function is recursive and pushes value of key needed to be renamed to original array with the new key, and unsets previous key:

**descriptive**

- foreach *$earth array* element check if elements key is in keys of *$rename array*
- if **is** , we add to this *$earth array* this element we are still at, but we assign it to key, met in value of matched *$rename arrays* key!
- then unset this *$earth arrays* element we encountered on.
- Done! If type of this element (encountered we on it or not) is array, function calls for itself.